# How to use lapply or another higher order function when calling tabPanel in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, tabpanel

I am using tabPanel in R shiny and would like to make the coder nicer by using a function like lapply

This is the tabBox

```
tabBox(
  title = mytitle, id = myid, width = "8",
  tabPanel(myTitle[1], icon = icon("adjust"), plotOutput(myPlot[1])),
  tabPanel(myTitle[2], icon = icon("adjust"), plotOutput(myPlot[2])),
  tabPanel(myTitle[3], icon = icon("adjust"), plotOutput(myPlot[3])),
  tabPanel(myTitle[4], icon = icon("adjust"), plotOutput(myPlot[4]))
)
```

the vectors myTitle and myPlot are defined as

```
myTitle=c("A","B","C","D")
myPlot =c("X1","X2","X3","X4")
```

How can I avoid repeated tabPanel definitions by using a higher order function, e.g. lapply or another one?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do.call(function(...){
  tabBox(title = mytitle, id = myid, width = "8", ...)
}, mapply(function(title, plotid){
  tabPanel(title, icon = icon("adjust"), plotOutput(plotid))
}, myTitle, myPlot, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
```

Not highly readable, but this avoids the repetitions.

Comment: Thanks Stephane for the handy answer!

Comment: @J.Doe Glad to help. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).